# String concatenation using Node js

Tags: node.js

I want my string to appear as what is shown below.

```
var ww = '{"q" : ["sdsds","Dog"] }';
```

I have a variable called `var arr`. When I `console.log(arr)` the output I get is `Elephant,Dog`.

How can I recreate the variable `ww` using the variable `arr` in it?

Comment: Why are you calling this "string concatenation"? Anyway, don't create or manipulate JSON using string arithmetic. Turn `ww` into a JavaScript object with `JSON.parse`, replace the `q` property with `object.q = arr;`, then turn it back into a JSON string with `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: I don't understand your solution. Can you elaborate .

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest using a Template Literal which is part of ES2015. I am going to assume the entire array is passed in and that you want to have a JSON string. Please modify to your desired output format.

```
var arr1 = ['ssds', 'dog']
var arr2 = ['elephant', 'dog']

function buildWW(arr) {
    return JSON.stringify(`{q: [${arr}]}`)
}

var ww = buildWW(arr1)
console.log(ww)

ww = buildWW(arr2)
console.log(ww)
```

Answer (score -2):

Using lodash library it could be easily done as:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var arr = '["Elephant", "Dog"]';

var ww = '{"q" : ["sdsds","Dog"] }';

arr = JSON.parse(arr); // skip if arr is javascript array
ww = JSON.parse(ww); // skip if ww is javascript object
ww.q = _.union(arr, ww.q);

ww = JSON.stringify(ww); //skip if ww is already javascript object
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Any particular reason to use lodash? This does not seem more complicated than `www.q.push(...arr)`.

Comment: The www.q.push(arr) will keep the duplicate entries. I have used the lodash union function to remove duplicate entries. However if you want to keep duplicate entries you can use array push method too.